# Evaluation of a triple sum does not finish in reasonable time

Tags: series-expansion

I'm trying to compute the following triple sum, but no result is produced within a reasonable amount of time. What to do?

```
Sum[1/( i j k (i + j + k + 1)), {i, 1, Infinity}, {j, 1, Infinity}, {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

I use *Mathematica* 8.0.

Comment: This works... `ParallelSum[Sum[Sum[1/(i j k (i + j + k + 1)), {i, 1, Infinity}] /. 
   j -> j1, {k, 1, Infinity}], {j1, 1, 50}]
` but note that it stops at j=50

Comment: FYI its value is 5.35132... does not seem to converge quickly though...

Comment: note that the value I gave you is for jmax=50 not infinity!

Comment: @chris You can get a closed form for one summation, it might help convergence.

Comment: @chris and are the two of you siblings ?

Comment: for `jmax=100` it yields `5.59365`. And no, no siblings!

Comment: Chris, my answer is incorrect: please accept the second answer by @b.gatessucks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

@whuber gave me another idea : first change the summand to an exponential and then do the sums using the symmetry.

```
Integrate[Exp[-t i j k (i + j + k + 1)], {t, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {i > 0, j > 0, k > 0}]
(* 1/(i j k (1 + i + j + k)) *)
```

so we need to do the sums of the exponential and then integrate at the end.
Now we can make a change of variables `t i j k = y` which will simplify the exponent and bring a factor `1/(i j k)` from the Jacobian. This makes it easier to see that

$$\sum_{i,j,k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i j k} \exp(-y\ (i+j+k+1)) = \exp(-y) \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i}\exp(-y\  i)\right)^3$$

```
Simplify[Sum[Exp[-y i]/i, {i, 1, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {y > 0}], 
  Assumptions -> {y > 0}]
(* -Log[1 - E^-y] *)
```

and we are left with the integration :

```
Integrate[Exp[-y] (-Log[1 - E^-y])^3, {y, 0, Infinity}]
(* 6 *)
```

It's also straightforward to generalize to the sum over `n` integers and the result is :

```
Integrate[Exp[-y] (-Log[1 - E^-y])^n, {y, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {n \[Element] Integers, n >= 1}] 
(* Gamma[1 + n] *)
```

Comment: Aside from justifying switching the order of integration and summation and a typo (missing $i$ in second summation), it looks good.  Numerically I got an upper bound of about `6.08` on the sum. (+1)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Fixed, thanks a lot.

Comment: Very nice idea! @Michael E2 has clearly identified my mistake, which now squares our two results. (I promised only to find a lower bound for the sum, so a numerical value of the integral around $3.5$ is just fine).  I apologize for making you work so hard :-) and will make up for it by transferring all the points from my answer to yours, which deserves it. (There's a day's wait before I can do that, though...)

Comment: @whuber You had the key insight and deserve most of the credit.

Comment: btw, congrats on your 10k!

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

Here is another variant along the same lines as @whuber proposed. Consider function
$$
f(x,y,z,t)=\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } \sum _{j=1}^{\infty } \sum
   _{k=1}^{\infty } x^{i-1} y^{j-1} z^{k-1} t^{i+j+k}.
$$
Mma gives

```
f[x_, y_, z_, t_] = 
 Sum[x^(i - 1) y^(j - 1) z^(k - 1) t^(i + j + k), {i, 
   1, \[Infinity]}, {j, 1, \[Infinity]}, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}]
```

$$
-\frac{t^3}{(t x-1) (t y-1) (t z-1)}.
$$
Then the required sum is equal to 
$$
\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1\int _0^1f(x,y,z,t)\,dzdydxdt,
$$

```
Integrate[f[x, y, z, t], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

which gives 6 as in the answer of @b.gatessucks.

Answer (score 6):

If I take the challenge to be to get *Mathematica* to do the sum in the form given (as distinct from applying some mathematics insightfully), then here is a way to get the answer.  The only trick I use is to break the triple sum into a double and single sum.

```
s2 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + k + 1)), {i, 1, Infinity}, {j, 1, Infinity}]; // Timing
(s2 = FullSimplify[s2]) // Timing
Sum[s2/k, {k, 1, Infinity}] // Timing
```

> ```
> {93.696694, Null}
> {0.234598, (\[Pi]^2 + 6 HarmonicNumber[1 + k]^2 - 6 PolyGamma[1, 2 + k])/(6 + 6 k)}
> {12.027743, 6}
> ```

The intermediate step of simplifying `s2` seems to be necessary.

Interestingly *Mathematica* caches auxiliary expressions in computing the sum.  The second time around is faster.  (Almost all the time is spent in `FullSimplify`)

```
(s2 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + k + 1)), {i, 1, Infinity}, {j, 1, Infinity}];
  s2 = FullSimplify[s2];
  Sum[s2/k, {k, 1, Infinity}]) // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.228539, 6}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but it might help.
You can get one summation in closed form :

```
sum1 = Sum[1/(i j k (i + j + k + 1)), {i, 1, Infinity}]
(* (EulerGamma + PolyGamma[0, 2 + j + k])/(j k (1 + j + k)) *)
```

You can also do the easy bit :

```
sum2 = Sum[Sum[EulerGamma/(j k (1 + j + k)), {j, 1, Infinity}], {k, 1, Infinity}]
(* 2 EulerGamma *)
```

so you're left with a double sum

```
sum = 2 EulerGamma + 
      Sum[PolyGamma[0, 2 + j + k]/(j k (1 + j + k)), {j, 1, Infinity}, {k, 1, Infinity}]
```

You can make some further simplification by using the symmetry of the summand or proceed numerically.