# A double series with divisibility restrictions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How may I restrict  $i,j$ such that they run over $\mathbb{N}$ excepting the numbers divisible by $2$ or $3$ or $7$?

```
Sum[1/( i j (i + j + 1)), {i, 1, Infinity}, {j, 1, Infinity}]
```

Comment: Could you please add a bit of context just to say how you got into this problem ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks I'm doing some personal research on multiseries.

Answer (score 4):

Could do explicit inclusion/exclusion as below (I forget what the correct term is but you'll get the idea). First do one index.

```
s1 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {j, 1, Infinity}];

s2 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {j, 2, Infinity, 2}];
s3 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {j, 3, Infinity, 3}];
s7 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {j, 7, Infinity, 7}];

s23 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {j, 2*3, Infinity, 2*3}];
s27 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {j, 2*7, Infinity, 2*7}];
s37 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {j, 3*7, Infinity, 3*7}];
s237 = Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {j, 2*3*7, Infinity, 2*3*7}];

stot = s1 - (s2 + s3 + s7) + (s23 + s27 + s37) - s237;
```

Can now repeat the process with the other index. Below would be the first step.

```
t1 = Sum[stot, {i, 1, Infinity}]
```

Unfortunately I cannot get a closed form for this.

If there is a way to rewrite as some form of convolution sum that might be amenable to Fourier series type methods. Offhand I don't see such a rewrite but I could easily be missing something of that sort.

Comment: OK. Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 3):

I tried to go the usual [tricky route](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24889/134) in order to use symmetries :

$$\sum_{i,j} \frac{1}{i\ j (i+j+1)} = \int_{0}^{\infty} dx\ e^{-x} \left(\sum_{i} \frac{e^{-i x}}{i} \right)^2$$

The sum can be performed in closed form :

```
s = Sum[Exp[-i x]/i Boole[Mod[i, 2] != 0] Boole[Mod[i, 3] != 0] Boole[
Mod[i, 7] != 0] , {i, 1, Infinity}]
```

but the integral cannot.
Numerically :

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-x] s s, {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* 0.480345 *)
```

which looks in line with @tintin.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `Boole` as follows:

```
Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)) Boole[! Divisible[i, 2] && ! 
     Divisible[i, 3] && ! Divisible[i, 7] && ! Divisible[j, 2] && ! 
     Divisible[j, 3] && ! Divisible[j, 7]], {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 
  1000}] // N
```

> 0.478819

Which gives the same numerical value as tintin's `Mod` version.

To speed things up, you can use the new iteration form in *Mathematica*

First define `lis` as follows:

```
lis = Select[Range[1, 1000, 2], Not@Divisible[#, 3] && Not@Divisible[#, 7] &] // N;
```

Then:

```
Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {i, lis}, {j, lis}]
```

> 0.478819

Comment: OK. Thank you for answer!

Comment: 2x speedup: add `N@` before `Select`

Comment: @ybeltukov. Yes, good point. And this makes the `// N` after `Sum` redundant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
f[i_, j_] := 0;
f[i_, j_] := 
 1/(i j (i + j + 1)) /;  
 Mod[i, 2] != 0 && Mod[i, 3] != 0 && Mod[i, 7] != 0 && 
   Mod[j, 2] != 0 && Mod[j, 3] != 0 && Mod[j, 7] != 0
```

you can sum it with

```
Sum[f[i,j],{i,1,1000},{j,1,1000}]
```

which I get the number of 
    0.478819
I write 1000 because I cant deal with the infinity thing

Comment: note you can do Sum[f[i, j], {i, 1, 1000, 2}, {j, 1, 1000, 2}] and omit the Mod[,2] check.. speed it up a tad.

Comment: @george2079,that is definately a big improvement

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this way too,

```
Total[Total[
   Table[If[(Divisible[i, #] && Divisible[j, #]) & /@ {2, 3, 7}  /. 
      List -> Or, 1/(i j (i + j + 1)), 0], {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 
     1000}]]] // N
```

> 0.344854

`Sum` will achieve the same result, its gives same result as a `Table` with two iterators as in your case.
If you do `NSum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 1000}]`
you get

> `SequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect.`
>   1.97715

But if you use `Total[Total[Table[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {i, 1, 1000}, {j, 1, 1000}]] //
   N]`

> 1.98443 (*No warnings*)

Now to see that same results are generated by `Sum` and custom loop check these,

```
Sum[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}] // N
```

> 1.81095

```
Total[Total[Table[1/(i j (i + j + 1)), {i, 1, 50}, {j, 1, 50}]] // N]
```

> 1.81095

'NSum' probably uses approximations hence its result is pretty close but might be wrong if high precision needed.