# Sum all numbers from 1 to 1000 divided by either 2,3,5 or 7

Tags: summation

How do I find the sum all numbers from 1 to 1000 divided by atleast one of 2,3,5 or 7?

EDIT: I am sorry for complicating this, but I need it to work for 10^11. So anything that requires too much heap space or too long loops will fail.

Comment: What did you try? And are you trying to solve some project Euler question?

Comment: Well, actually it is for Prob 432. But for very a big number (instead of 1000, it is 10^11) and so anything other than a pure mathematical aproach will fail.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32273/a-double-series-with-divisibility-restrictions

Comment: @Blackbird It's related, but definitely is not a duplicate. Here you have finite sums (of divergent series), there are symbolic infinite sums of convergent series. So e.g. efficiency is especially important.

Comment: @Roi Consider registering your account, so that you'll be able to better interact with this site.

Comment: (Not really the way to do this, but...) `sumFunction := 
 Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{sum = 0}, 
   Do[If[k/2. == Quotient[k, 2] || k/3. == Quotient[k, 3] || 
      k/5. == Quotient[k, 5] || k/7. == Quotient[k, 7], sum += k], {k,
      n}]; sum], CompilationTarget -> "C"]` Takes a minute to handle 10^9. Scales with the input value so should handle 10^11 in under 2 hrs. Much larger and Compile won't handle it-- that sum will exceed capacity of 64 bit long ints. (Now ask me if I'm embarassed I posted this.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
sum[n_, d_] = Sum[d k, {k, Floor[n/d]}];
f[n_] := Total[-(-1)^Length@# sum[n, Times @@ #] & /@ Subsets[{2, 3, 5, 7}, {1, 4}]]
```

Example

```
f[10^11]
```

> 3857142857207142857139

Comment: Beat me to it. Mathematica is a great fit for the mixed analytical/numerical solutions. There's however a 20 fold performance increase hiding in plain sight, you just need to remove one character. Reply back if you want the specifics. :)

Comment: @jVincent He found it :)

Comment: I think `Rest@Subsets[{2, 3, 5, 7}]` is more flexible.:)

Comment: @chyanog  Or perhaps `Subsets[#, {1, Length@#}] &@ {2, 3, 5, 7}'. :)

Answer (score 5):

If we are to deal with big numbers we should exploit symbolic capabilities of the system. This
`Sum[ k Boole[Or @@ Divisible[k, {2, 3, 5, 7}]], {k, n} ]` would be useful for `n < 10^7` but for `n > 10^9` we have to provide **a neat modification**.
We can observe that `Sum` is needed  only for a small subset of the whole range $\{1, \cdots , n\}$.
Since we have:

- $2\times 3\times  5\times  7 = 210$
- `Count[ Range @ 210, _?(Or @@ Divisible[#, {2, 3, 5, 7}] &)]` $\quad$  yields `162`.
- `Sum[ k Boole[Or @@ Divisible[k, {2, 3, 5, 7}]], {k, 210}]` $\quad$ yields `17115`.

We define the following function:

```
f[n_Integer]/; n >= 1 := 
    With[{ c = Floor[n/210]}, 
          ( 17115 + 162 210 (c - 1)/2) c
            + Sum[k Boole[Or @@ Divisible[k, {2, 3, 5, 7}]], {k, 210 c + 1, n}]]
```

Now it works nicely also for big numbers:

```
 f /@ {1000, 10^11}
```

> ```
> {386788, 3857142857207142857139}
> ```

or even for much much bigger:

```
 IntegerDigits[ f[10^10^6]] // Short
```

> ```
> { 3, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 
>     <<1999970>>, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 8, 5, 8, 5}
> ```

Comment: I think you were faster, so I deleted my answer and you have my vote :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks, I think you shouldn't delete your post but rather adding another way.

Comment: Hehe here I am talking about the least common multiple of prime numbers. You did what my answer was hinting at, I like it.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Upvoted your answer too. Nonetheless I think the answers given haven't been sufficiently appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean divisible by at least one of those numbers? If so, how about

```
Select[Range[1000], Or @@ Divisible[#, {2, 3, 5, 7}] &] // Total
```

> 386788

If you want to have the answer for a large range of numbers, you can just get the answer for a small range, up to at least the least common multiple (LCM) of the numbers. You then have the relation

```
numbersWithProperty[Range[lCM]] == numbersWithProperty[Range[k*lCM+1, (k+1)lCM]] - k*lCM
```

for

```
numbersWithProperty[list_] :=

 Select[list, Or @@ Divisible[#, {2, 3, 5, 7}] &]
```

and

```
lCM = LCM[2, 3, 5, 7];
```

and for example `k=1`

Perhaps it is a good exercise to figure out how to finish the exercise using this?

Answer (score 4):

```
Pick[#, Times @@ Table[#~Mod~i, {i, {2, 3, 5, 7}}], 0] &@Range[1000] //Tr
(*386788*)

n /. Solve[{n~Mod~2 n~Mod~3 n~Mod~5 n~Mod~7 == 0, 0 < n <= 10^3}, n, Integers] // Tr
(*386788*)
```

Following two would be worked for a huge number:

```
Sum[(1 - Unitize[i~Mod~2 i~Mod~3 i~Mod~5 i~Mod~7]) i, {i, n}];
% /. n -> 10^11
(*3857142857207142857139*)

Times @@@ # & /@ GatherBy[Rest@Subsets[{2, 3, 5, 7}], Length]
MapIndexed[Tr[(-1)^(#2 - 1)] Boole@Thread[Mod[i, #] == 0] &, %]
Total[%, -1]
Sum[(%) i, {i, n}] // Simplify
% /. n -> 10^11
(*3857142857207142857139*)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Part` is good for this purpose.

```
list = Range[1000];

Total[
 Union[
  list[[2 ;; ;; 2]],
  list[[3 ;; ;; 3]],
  list[[5 ;; ;; 5]],
  list[[7 ;; ;; 7]]
  ]
 ]
```

Or more compactly:

```
Total[
 Union @@ (list[[# ;; ;; #]] & /@ {2, 3, 5, 7})
 ]
```

(Obviously this doesn't conform to the modified requirements though.)